# evitar poner onclick en tabla

Tags: javascript, ajax, eventos

tengo un problema. Tengo una tabla llena de datos y cada registro de esta tabla tiene 2 botones, `show y delete`. Estos botones tienen que disparar una funcion de JS que hará una peticion al servidor. Mi problema es que no quiero poner `onclick="show($paciente->id)"` en cada registro, ya que no creo que sea una buena practica, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer para saber cual es el boton que esta presionando, ya que todos dispararan la misma funcion pero enviaran un `id` diferente.

```
@foreach ($pacientes as $paciente)
    <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ $paciente->id}}</th>
        <td>{{ $paciente->nombre }}</td>
        <td>{{ $paciente->apellidos }}</td>
        <td>{{ $paciente->carnet }}</td>
        <td>{{ $paciente->fecha_nacimiento }}</td>
        <td>{{ $paciente->telefono }}</td>
        <td>{{ $paciente->direccion }}</td>
        <td>{{ $paciente->strikes }}</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="showUser" onclick="showUser({{ $paciente->ID}})" class="showUser" ><i class="far fa-eye"></i> Ver</a></td>
        <td><a href="#" id="deleteUser" class="deleteUser"><i class="far fa-trash"></i> Eliminar</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Intenté con JS algo asi, pero no funcionó.

```
let showButton = document.querySelector('.showUser');
// let deleteButton = document.getElementById('deleteUser');
showButton.forEach((element) => {
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert(element.value);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como lo tienes sin JQuery esta bien solo haria unos cambios

```
let showButton = document.querySelectorAll('.showUser');
showButton.forEach((element) => {
   element.addEventListener('click', function(){
     alert(element.getAttribute('Nombre_del_atributo'));
   })
})
```

los cambios que realicé en tu codigo fueron:

el método **querySelector()**, lo cambie por **querySelectorAll()**
ya que el como tu lo tenias hace referencia al primer elemento que encuentre, mientras que querySelectorAll es en todas las coincidencias que haya en el dom

y el segundo cambio que hice fue reemplazar la propiedad **value** por el metodo **getAttribute()** ya que Value es solo para inputs, y al utilizar este metodo te permitiria introducir el id en el elemento como un atributo y acceder a el

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar jQuery la función on te ayuda a añadir eventos sobre elementos que todavia no han sido renderizados

```
$("table").on("click", ".showUser", function(){
   const row = $(this).parent().parent()
   const paciente_id = row.find('th[scope="row"]').html()
})
```

Comment: Claro, logro hacer que el evento se dispare, pero el problema es como saber cual es el `value` del elemento que di click.

Comment: modifique para ayudarte tambien a obtener el id directamente del th que tienes dentro del <tr>

Comment: Perfecto. Muchas gracias... no estoy usando JQuery pero entendí la logica y ya lo hice